# Is it possible to adjust exposure in cwac-camera when in Preview mode?

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I'm playing with cwac-camera and it's a great library. I need to know if I can adjust the exposure compensation at real time when in preview mode. E.g.: is it possible to use the SeekBar in the CameraFragment demo to modify exposure instead of zoom level?

I succeeded saving picture with exposure compensation programmatically set at min or max level but I would like to be able to adjust before taking a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to know if I can adjust the exposure compensation at real time when in preview mode

No. And to the extent that is possible today, it will not be possible in the future, as changing `Camera.Parameters` with a live preview seems to be a major source of my lingering device incompatibilities.